# Rotation of a Sprite in andengine

Tags: andengine

i want to rotate the needle of meter used in my game around its axis how it is possible?

> needleSprite.setRotationCenter(this.getRotationCenterX(),
>   this.getRotationCenterY()); needleSprite.registerEntityModifier(new
>   RotationModifier(6f, 0, 270));

Answer (score 1):

`needleSpirte.setRotation(float);`